# How to expect non-string values in redigomock

Tags: go, redigo

I'm new to redigomock, and through the documentation and googling I simply can't find a valid example. I'm missing something obvious, but I would like my tests to work.

Given this code:

```
var checkPasswordFailures = func(client redis.Conn, u *User) bool {
    var userkey = getPasswordFailKey(u)
    var existing, err = redis.Bool(client.Do("EXISTS", userkey))

    fmt.Printf("%s - existing = %v\n", userkey, existing)

    if err != nil {
        Log.Errorf("error in checkPasswordFailures: %s", err.Error())
    }
    if existing == true {
        fmt.Println("Existing true")
        reply, err := redis.Int(client.Do("GET", userkey))

        Log.Debug("Attempt Count: %d", reply)

        if err != nil {
            Log.Errorf("error in checkPasswordFailures: %s", err.Error())
        }
        return reply < 5
    }
    fmt.Println("Using default")
    return true
}
```

And this test:

```html
func TestCheckPasswordFailures_LessThan5(t *testing.T) {

 conn := redigomock.NewConn()

 conn.Command("EXISTS", "test@xxx.com_pwf").Expect(true)
 conn.Command("GET", "test@xxx.com_pwf").Expect(3)

 actual := checkPasswordFailures(conn, mockUser)

 assert.True(t, actual)

}
```

I receive an error:

> redigo: unexpected type for Bool, got type bool

I've tried many approaches to coerce the value into the expected result, but to no avail.

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4):

```js
func TestCheckPasswordFailures_LessThan5(t *testing.T) {

conn := redigomock.NewConn()

conn.Command("EXISTS", "test@xxx.com_pwf").Expect([]byte("true"))
conn.Command("GET", "test@xxx.com_pwf").Expect(int64(1))

actual := checkPasswordFailures(conn, mockUser)

assert.True(t, actual)
}
```